# Formatting error while rotating header in table

Tags: html, css, header, rotation, html-table

I am working on table in which i rotate table to fit all the big header names using following code.

```
<html><body>

<style type="text/css">
.tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:1%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #ebab3a;border-collapse: collapse;}
.tftable th {font-size:12px;border-width:1px;padding: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ebab3a;text-align:left;}
.tftable tr { line-height: 14px;}
.tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ebab3a;height: 14px;}
.tftable tr:hover {background-color:#ffffff;border:none;}
th.rotate {
  /* Something you can count on */
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th.rotate > div {
  transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(25px, 51px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(270deg);
  width: 30px;
}
th.rotate > div  {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
</style>



<table class="tftable" border="1">
<tr><th class="rotate"><div>Metabolite</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th><th class="rotate"><div>Experiment</div></th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="green">Metabolilte1</td><td> 2</td><td> 3</td><td> 4</td><td> 5</td><td> 6</td><td> 7</td><td> 8</td><td> 9</td><td> 10</td><td> 11</td><td> 12</td><td> 13</td><td> 14</td><td> 15</td></tr>
<tr><td>Metabolilte2</td><td> 2</td><td> 3</td><td> 4</td><td> 5</td><td> 6</td><td> 7</td><td> 8</td><td> 9</td><td> 10</td><td> 11</td><td> 12</td><td> 13</td><td> 14</td><td> 15</td></tr>
<tr><td>Metabolilte3</td><td> 2</td><td> 3</td><td> 4</td><td> 5</td><td> 6</td><td> 7</td><td> 8</td><td> 9</td><td> 10</td><td> 11</td><td> 12</td><td> 13</td><td> 14</td><td> 15</td></tr>
<tr><td>Metabolilte4</td><td> 2</td><td> 3</td><td> 4</td><td> 5</td><td> 6</td><td> 7</td><td> 8</td><td> 9</td><td> 10</td><td> 11</td><td> 12</td><td> 13</td><td> 14</td><td> 15</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

[image]

Why is the second column header blank and the last column header appearing outside of the table?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @dogwoodtree-dot-net i am trying to write rotated header but i found 2nd header is empty as there and last one is coming out.

Answer (score 0):

first parameter of "translate" should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

We have rotation code:

```
th.rotate > div {
  transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(25px, 51px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(270deg);
  width: 30px;
}
```

These are not *Magic Numbers*. `translate(x,y)` method moves element `x` pixels on x-axis and `y` pixels on y-axis. In your code it's 25px to the right and 51px down. Changing value of `x` to 0 will avoid unwanted translation to the right, so change `translate(25px, 51px)` to `translate(0px, 51px)` (see http://plnkr.co/edit/eZS9xVtFGkxgraibV55z).

Now we can play with translation on y-axis and size of table header element. Let's set translation on `y` to `20px` and height of `th` element to `80px` (see http://plnkr.co/edit/kZkI8GDiWlwU1t28lOWO).